# How do I get all heroes to the same map location in Dota 2

Tags: dota-2

When playing Dota 2 how do I get other heroes to support my hero?

Notice I keep dying when all opponent heroes arrive at the one location and make a 5 versus 1 battle against my hero. However, I do not seem to be able to achieve this tactic against my opponents. I am playing beginner mode if that affects the answer.

While I can transport my hero to support hero locations I really want to be able to have my support heroes attack a location or opponent hero I feel is critical.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you referring to controlling bots or other players?

Comment: @Allure         In Controlling bots

Answer (score 1):

Use pings (ALT + Left Click) on enemy heroes and objects. This will help focus the bots' attention on your targets.